# Swift: Slider value and number-string conversion

Tags: swift

I am practicing the TipCalculator App with Swift. Swift is my new language. Since the demo code with Xcode 6.0 does not match with Xcode 8, there are two issues.

No. 1 Issue: Argument label '(integer:)' do not match any available overloads.

```
let sliderValue =
    NSDecimalNumber(integer: Int(customTipPercentageSlider.value))
```

No. 2 Issue: Type 'NumberFormatter' has no number 'CurrencyStyle'

```
func formatAsCurrency(number: NSNumber) -> String {
    return NumberFormatter.localizedStringFromNumber(
        number, numberStyle: NumberFormatter.CurrencyStyle)
}
```

Please see the source code in the following weblink. 
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2273069&seqNum=6

Please indicate how to correct the two issues.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Answer #1:

If you want to convert a Float (the slider.value type) to an Int, simply typecast it.

```
let sliderValue = Int(customTipPercentageSlider.value)
```

Answer #2:

I think you're looking for Swift 3 syntax here.

```
func formatAsCurrency(number: NSNumber) -> String {
    return NumberFormatter.localizedString(from: number, numberStyle: .currency)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pleased to put the code as follows. In regard to the last line of code, Xcode shows Binary operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'NSDeimalNumber'

```
@IBAction func calculateTip(_ sender: Any) {
    func sliderValueChanged(_ sender: Any) {
    }
    let inputString = inputTextField.text  // get the user input
    let sliderValue = Int(customTipPercentageSlider.value)
    let customPercent = sliderValue / decimal100
```

Comment: Check out my answer for a solution to this problem. Also, updating your code should happen within your post, not as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @dfd's answer, I would recommend using the `Double` type instead of `NSDecimalNumber` because it is easier to convert to / from `Int`. Thus if you initialize your `decimal100` variable like so:

```
var decimal100: Double = Double()
```

Then you could use the following code with issue:

```
let inputString = inputTextField.text  // get the user input
let sliderValue = Int(customTipPercentageSlider.value)
let customPercent = Double(sliderValue) / decimal100
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let sliderValue =
    NSDecimalNumber(integer: Int(customTipPercentageSlider.value))
```

you are getting this error as there is no initialiser for NSDecimalNUmber for integer.
The initialisers available in swift 3 are:

```
init(decimal: Decimal)
init(mantissa: UInt64, exponent: Int16, isNegative: Bool)
init(string: String?)
init(string: String?, locale: Any?)
```

reference : https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdecimalnumber

You can use this for for formatting currency in swift

```
func formatAsCurrency(number: NSNumber) -> String {
        return NumberFormatter.localizedString(from: number, number: .currency)
    }
```

Comment: Sorry for the down vote, but what's different from my answer (well, except you didn't answer the first question)?

Comment: Thanks for your great help. It seems work right now. But I have a new problem as follows.

Comment: It shows '/' operator is wrong for the line of code:   let customPercent = sliderValue / decimal100

Comment: It seems that it has something wrong with the line of code: let customPercent = sliderValue / decimal100. But I can not solve it right now.

Comment: @MikeChen this could be your work around for your tip calculation          `let sliderValue = NSDecimalNumber(value:slider.value) as Decimal
let decimal100 =  NSDecimalNumber(string: "100") as Decimal
let tip = sliderValue/decimal100 // tip in percentage
let billAmount = NSDecimalNumber(string: "1000") as Decimal
let tipValue = (billAmount as Decimal) * tip //tip amount
let totalAmount = (tipValue + billAmount) as NSDecimalNumber
let finalDisplayText  = NumberFormatter.localizedString(from: NSNumber(value: totalAmount.doubleValue) , number: .currency)`

Comment: Argument label '(integer:)' do not match any available overloads. I finally found out the right answer. It works successfully. 

        let sliderValue =
        NSDecimalNumber(value: Int(customTipPercentageSlider.value) as Int)